# What nodes to use for enhancing an image texture imported as a plane

Tags: node-editor

I have created a mesh plane with two image texture nodes. I want to improve the quality/color of the "A Logo Text" image so I can make it stand out from the 2nd image texture.

I've to go through some node tutorials and tried to plug in various nodes, but I'm at a total loss.

What nodes can I use to enhance the "A Logo Text" image? and where would I plug it in?

The "A Logo Text" is a .png image with an alpha channel for the background as shown here.
My version of Blender is 2.82.7

[image: Two image textured plane]

Here is some of the progress I made following moonboots suggestions[image]

Comment: "enhance" is a bit too vague, try the Color nodes, like for example RGB Curves if you want to control the general RGB intensities

Comment: Thanks. You gave me an idea and direction to go in. I see they have a hue, saturation and contrast nodes, I can insert between the image texture node and the add node. This make the text pop out, what I meant by enhancing

Comment: I think you need to put a Diffuse (or Principled BSDF) after the Math node

Comment: I was trying not to be too verbose in my original question. I am making a video title effect following the tutorial of tutor 4u seen in this link where he creates an animated scroll in blender https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aes92iyzFWA  Following that example, I created the scroll and some text overlay in my video editor as seen in this link https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xW9HqTfLzeznSWPlDfkm63mNTA_eZPga  What I really want now is to make the text scroll out as if it is written on the paper itself. So I need two texture images but I want the text to stand out as shown in my clip

Comment: I tried the principal shader as suggested but my adjustments on the different setting did not produce a satisfactory result.  I will edit my original entry where I can add another picture of what I have accomplished based on your suggestions

Comment: maybe you need to use an Emission shader instead of a Diffuse, it will make the letters lightening...

Comment: Why do you suggest after the math node. I really only want the text to stand out. The background is supposed to look like old paper

Comment: I've been working in the Shader tab, maybe I should be working in the compositor tab, but that leaves even more confused on where to start.

Comment: it depends on what you mean by "stand out", for example if you need a glow effect in Cycles, you'll need to use the compositor, if you need the letters to be bright, use an Emission instead of a Diffuse, mix with the background (page texture) in a Mix Shader with the alpha plugged into the alpha socket of the Mix Shader, etc...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108001/discussion-between-claus-and-moonboots).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your text image needs to be a PNG with a 0% alpha background (transparent background). Then use this nodes setup: plug the 2 *Image Texture* nodes into 2 *Diffuse* nodes, mix them into a *Mix Shader*, use the text alpha as the factor of the *Mix Shader*:

[image]

Comment: Bless your patience with these questions :).

Comment: Thanks Jachym!!